# Send SMS programmatically without showing message controller

Tags: iphone, sms

I want to send SMS programmatically without showing message controller (for jailbroken iPhone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not send silent sms from app in iOS if you do these things then apple will reject your application this is not in apple guideline. if you want to do this you have to send it from a webserver using webservices.

Comment: Yeah you can use some SMS gateway to do the job. smsglobal.com is cheap and allows you to change the sender number (As long as you explain then what your app is doing and prove you're doing anything illegal and the user has approved the operation.)